# Class of all simple measurable functions are dense in Orlicz space with finite measure?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, orlicz-spaces

I know that if $S$ is the class of all complex, measurable, simple functions on $X$ such that $\mu\{x:s(x)\neq0\}<\infty$. If $1\leq p <\infty$ then $S$ is dense in $L^{p}(\mu).$

What I want to know is that is this result holds for Orlicz space also.
I mean, can I say that
Let $S$ be the class of all complex, measurable, simple functions on $X$ such that $\mu\{x:s(x)\neq0\}<\infty$.Then $S$ is dense in $L^{\Phi}(\mu$, where $\mu(X)<\infty.$
My intuition says that it is true. Is there any result like this?